# Laravel Auth Middleware: Class can does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to protect a route via middleware as [described in the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-middleware)

When I hit the url, I get:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 749:
Class can does not exist
```

Here's the relevant part from `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('{user}/profile/edit/{type?}', [
    'as'   => 'edit',
    'uses' => 'User\UserController@edit',
    'middleware' => ['can:edit-user,user'],
]);
```

`AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    // ... other definitions

    Gate::define('edit-user', function ($user, $subjectUser) {
        return
            $user->hasRole('manage.user') // if the user has this role, green
            ||
            ($user->isAdmin && $user->id == $subjectUser->id) // otherwise if is admin, can edit her own profile
            ;
    });
```

Maybe it's because I'm not using a separate policy class for defining the gate?

Comment: I tried adding a separate policy class for User and moving the check logic over there; same result.

Comment: You're registering your middleware as a class called `can` in `'middleware' => ['can:edit-user,user'],` - that's in fact what your error message is telling you. Where is that class defined?

Comment: @thebluefox I don't know. I do what the Laravel doc says. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-middleware did you check?) Just browsing through Laravel's source and I don't see a `Can` class. I also tried replacing `can` with auth, authorize and gate.

Comment: Look at how Middleware is registered [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

Comment: @thebluefox You're right. The routeMiddleware definition 'can' was missing from my app's Kernel https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/app/Http/Kernel.php#L52
Add it as an answer and I'll accept it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation on using Middleware with Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) - you need to register the definition in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

> If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

The error you're seeing shows that this definition is missing. You need to add something like;

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'can' => \Path\To\Your\Middleware::class,
];
```